# What bases are fit for human consumption and can be used in foods?

Tags: acid-base, food-chemistry

I know that are several acids that can be found in the kitchen, such as citric acid and vinegar.

However, I never heard of a base that can be used in the kitchen to raise the pH levels of any food. I am well aware that this mix would probably make a salt as a result. Something like hydrogen peroxide doesn't sound safe for food. So, my question is:

**What are (if any) the bases that can be used on those acids and still be human-consumable?**

Comment: I edited your post but didn't correct the part about "a base that can be used in the kitchen to reduce the pH levels of any food" - I'm pretty sure you mean *raise* the pH levels. You can/should edit your question for clarity on that point.

Comment: Thanks @ToddMinehardt, it has been a while since I last took Chemistry. Anyway, I should've checked it before posting, but thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately Googling for "alkaline food" these days is a bad idea; results are dominated by nonsense sites espousing the "[alkaline diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_diet)" nonsense / [woo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience).

There aren't many foods that are naturally alkaline.  The two exceptions I know of are:

- [baking soda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate)
- [egg white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_white)

Sometimes when I'm cooking and accidentally add too much acid (e.g. lemon juice or vinegar) to a broth or sauce, I can partially correct the mistake by adding small amounts of baking soda.  This converts the excess acid to the sodium salt and $\ce{CO2}$ is evolved.  For the example of vinegar (acetic acid):

$\ce{CH3COOH + NaHCO3 -> CO2(g) + CH3COONa + H2O}$

So sodium acetate salt is left behind, which limits the degree to which you can correct overaddition of acid.  (You don't want your food to be too salty.)$%edit$

Comment: sodium acetate itself is also basic and sometimes used with food